# How to know if a function is called first time or not

Tags: php

I want to create a function such that if it is called the first time, it behaves differently and for rest of the time it behaves differently. Now to do this I know I can use a "state" variable. Some other techniques were also given here:
[Check if function has been called yet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1933050/check-if-function-has-been-called-yet)

However I somehow got a hint from a colleague that debug_backtrace() can be used to solve this problem. I read about it but cannot understand how ? This function gives a stack trace of the function call. How can this tell if the function has been called first time or not ?

The exact code that baffles me is here:

```
/**
 * Holds the states of first timers
 * @var array
 */
private static $firstTimeCSS=array();
private static $firstTimeJS=array();
/**
 * Tells whether it is the first time this function is called on 
 * ANY CLASS object or not. Useful for one-time scripts and styles
 * 
 * @param string $class name optional. Usually you should send __CLASS__ to this, otherwise the instance ($this) class would be used.
 * @return boolean
 */
final protected function IsFirstTime($class=null)
{
    $t=debug_backtrace();
    if ($t[1]['function']=="JS")
        $arr=&self::$firstTimeJS;
    else
        $arr=&self::$firstTimeCSS;


    if ($class===null)
        $class=$this->Class;
    if (isset($arr[$class]))
        return false;
    else
    {
        $arr[$class]=true;
        return true;
    }   
}
```

Comment: Have you tried running a function twice and comparing the outputs of debug_backtrace?

Comment: Yes. The output only differs in array[0]['Line'] i.e. only the line number changes...which I guess is correct, because the stack trace is not changed. It still is calling the same function with same rules and path.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I personally don't see how this is possible or why you would want to do it this way. I suspect `debug_backtrace()` is a lot more expensive than a `static` variable, to begin with.

The only backtrace characteristic that seems to change between calls is, as you pointed out, the line number (from where the function was called). And, that wouldn't even change if you ran the functions in, say, a loop, since they would all be called from the same line on each iteration.

- Demonstration 1 (individual calls): [**CodePad**](http://codepad.org/FTFi1OGQ)
- Demonstration 2 (loop): [**CodePad**](http://codepad.org/IHkj9f9l)

If I were you, I'd stick with a state variable; as for your colleague, you could perhaps ask him to show you a code which demonstrates his methodology if you're curious as to how it works (I know I am!).

**Edit (from comments):** Basically, your colleague's `debug_backtrace()` method stores a boolean value in an array using the *key of the class which is called*.

In plain English, here's what happens:

- Is the calling function called "JS"?
- If so, store in a JS-labelled array; otherwise, use a CSS-labelled array.
- Check if a class was specified; if it wasn't, use this class.
- If we have a boolean value for *the given class* in the labelled array, it's not the first time.
- Otherwise, set the boolean value for *the given class* to true.

I know what you're thinking: This makes no sense, it doesn't even store the calling function's name! And you'd be right; this method is not extensible, and has a huge overhead.

If you want to do what this method does, just use a static variable in the class in question to keep track of whether or not functions have been called. Your colleague's method—sorry to say—is inefficient and ineffective.

Comment: @user1834562 Ah, okay. I've updated my post with some information on that. I really struggle to understand why the function you shared would be useful to anyone.

Comment: My question is that when he checks function name = "JS", how does that line tells if this function has been called before or not. It just tells that the "JS" functions is been called from somewhere.

Comment: @user1834562 Exactly, it only stores truth values per-class for "functions called `JS`" and "functions not called `JS`". As I said in my edit, this method is not extensible (for the reason you just described).

Comment: OK..now I get it..finally. There is nothing new here. Like you said, the check for "first-time-use" is not done via debug_backtrace(), but is done via storing a token in the static array. Thanks!! :)

Comment: No problem! As a general rule, if an answer helped you solve the problem, you can mark it as "correct" by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer. Happy coding! :)

Comment: @Orangepill This isn't the whole code. Static can't be used outside class context.

Comment: @user1834562 Actually you can! Take a look at the first demo; you can use a `static` variable inside any function. Take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6188994/1438733) for details on that.

Comment: @Eric: Thanks...this was really something new.

Comment: @Orangepill: I owe you an apology ... ^__^

Answer (score 0):

Take A hidden input field and

```
<input type="hidden" id="start_function_count" value="0">
```

and then call a function

```
<li  onclick="myFunction('start_function_count')">
```

js function

```
MyFunction(count_id) {
    var function_count = $("#"+count_id).val();
    if(function_count == 0){
        // CODE HERE for 1st time function call
        // SET HIDDEN FIELD
        $("#"+count_id).val(1);
    } else{
        // SECOnd time code;
    }
}
```

Comment: One should never replace server-side checks with client-side checks. Client can send anything to the server, bypass any verification, or the form itself. **Never trust clients, even if you think you can control the code it runs**

Answer (score 0):

just use a static field in the function. This static field will only be initialized once and not overwritten on new function calls.

If you use this in class methods, do take care that each inherited child class will have it's own version. So a static function field updated in `ParentClass` won't update the static function field in `ChildClass extends ParentClass`.

See it in action https://ideone.com/iR7J5O

```
function beDifferentFirstTime() 
{
  static $firstTime = true;
  if($firstTime) {
     $firstTime = false;
     echo "I will say this only once, so listen carefully\n";
  }
  echo "The cabbage is in the cart. I repeat, the cabbage is in the cart.\n";
}
beDifferentFirstTime();
beDifferentFirstTime();
```